# Azure AD B2C - Email Claim Fails with Null Value

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using custom policies in Azure AD B2C to specify custom providers (in this case, GitHub OAuth). The email claim throws an internal server error in Azure AD B2C if the email claim contains something like, "email": null. I validated that this was the value using the App Insights trace log, which contained the full OAuth response from GitHub. However, it always fails on the self asserted step.

Here is a snippet from the trace logs:

```
"GitHub-OAUTH": {
    "ContentType": "Json",
    "Created": "2018-01-05T01:33:49.5316319Z",
    "Key": "GitHub-OAUTH",
    "Persistent": true,
    "Value": "{\"id\":1234,<snip>\"email\":null,<snip>,\"{oauth2:access_token}\":\"mytoken\"};2;GitHub-OAUTH;False"
},
"Complex-CLMS": {
    "gitHubUserId": "1234",
    "displayName": "My Name",
    "githubEmail": "Null",
    "identityProvider": "github.com",
    "authenticationSource": "socialIdpAuthentication",
    "upnUserName": "1234",
    "userPrincipalName": "cpim_1234@apollohackfest.onmicrosoft.com",
    "socialIdpUserId": "1234",
    "alternativeSecurityId": "{\"type\":6,\"identityProvider\":\"github.com\",\"key\":\"abcdefg=\"}"
}
```

If the email address is instead email: "myemail@site.com", then the login works fine. Or, if the OAUTH provider does not return an email field at all, it also works fine. This only breaks in the case of email: null.

I don't want there to be internal server errors when providers give null results. Is there a claim transformation that I can use to remove email claim when this happens?

Comment: If you remove the restriction, does the problem go away? I thought the regex is evaluated only when user gives input not when a claim is received from another provider, hence the question. If the value received is { "email":"Null" } or { "email" : null } then it should work but I can see it fail if its { "email" : Null } because that may be considered invalid json.

Comment: You are correct that removing validation did not fix the issue. It looks like it is the null value itself. In postman, it looks like the response is correctly {"email": null}, but B2C still fails with server error when handling this case. It does not fail in instances when email is an instantiated string. Default values also do not help in these instances. Do you know of any workarounds?